# A finite group is a product of cyclic groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$.  There exists a sequence of cyclic subgroups $H_1, ..., H_n$, not necessarily distinct, such that $H$ is the product $H = H_1H_2\cdots H_n = \{ h_1h_2\cdots h_n : h_i\in H_i,\forall i\}$.

Comment: I don't see why arbitrary finite groups could be written as products of cyclic groups (and obviously *internal direct* products would be false), nor how this could be used to find subgroups of small groups. Every group is generated by cyclic groups, though.

Comment: @anon I don't think OP means direct product, but rather "subgroup products."

Comment: How are you defining $H_1H_2$? Is it the smallest subgroup contain $H_1$ and $H_2$, or is it the set $\{h_1h_2:h_1\in H_1, h_2\in H_2\}$? The latter is not a subgroup.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's why I distinguished the two.

Comment: Sorry, brain death, I thought you were OP replying to my second comment. @anon

Comment: I rewrote it guys.

Comment: Just take all cyclic subgroups of $H$...

Comment: It is trivially true as asked. An interesting question arises if one also imposes uniqueness on the product decomposition of the group elements.  Then I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $H_1$, $\dots$, $H_n$ be the list of all cyclic subgroups of $H$. Then $H=H_1\dots H_n$.

Indeed, every element $x$ of $H$ belongs to one of the $H_i$ (for example, to the cyclic group it generates), and if $H_k$ is one which contains it then $$x=\underbrace{e\cdot e\cdot\cdots\cdot e}_{\text{$k-1$ factors}}\cdot x\cdot \underbrace{e\cdot\cdots\cdot e}_{\text{$n-k$ factors}}\in H_1\cdots H_n.$$

Comment: Cool, i see how that works.

Comment: Can you drop to the chat, Mariano?

Answer (score 2):

This is true, but I don't know how useful it's going to be, because the cyclic subgroups of $G$ aren't enough to characterize the structure of $G$. For example, the modular group of order 16,
$$M_{16}=\langle a,b~|~a^2=b^8=1,ba=ab^5\rangle,$$
and the product of cyclic groups of orders 2 and 8,
$$C_2\times C_8 = \langle a,b~|~a^2=b^8=1, ba=ab\rangle,$$
have the same [cycle graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph_%28algebra%29).