# Representation of an element of an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Any finite group $G$ can be decomposed as a direct product of its cyclic groups. Let

$$G =\langle g_1 \rangle \times \langle g_2 \rangle \times \ldots \times \langle g_t \rangle$$

where the order of each $g_i$ is $c_i$ for $i \in \{1,...,i\}$. For any $g \in G$ one can write

$$g = (g_1^{\alpha_1},g_2^{\alpha_2},\ldots,g_t^{\alpha_t})$$

Where $\alpha_i \le c_i$ for all $i \in[t]$.

**Questions :** Is it true that $g = g_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot g_2^{\alpha_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot g_t^{\alpha_t} $ where $\cdot$ is the group operation of $G$?

I have tried for

$Z_{15} = Z_5 \times Z_3$.

Comment: If the $\alpha$'s in your question are the same as the ones denoting the order of each $g_i$, then obviously not. Since this would imply that every $g$ is the identity.

Comment: @ NDewolf  I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is true. See for example the answer to [A finite group is a product of cyclic groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460799/a-finite-group-is-a-product-of-cyclic-groups)

For every $g_i$ you can write $g_i=\underbrace{e\cdots e}_{i-1\text{ times}}\cdot g_i\cdot\underbrace{e\cdots e}_{t-i\text{ times}}$ and this immediately implies your decomposition.